# The database structure to scale the table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am writing a name card storage system. It works like this, first, a company register on my website, then they are given an account, and start saving name card on my server.

The database is like this:

```
Company
-id
-name
-address

Card
-id
-name
-title
-*company_id
```

The problem is, is this simple structure can fulfil the need when there are more than 100,000 company, if one company has 1000 cards then the card table will be very huge and the query time is long.

How to scale the table, given that I don't know the actual number of the company, should I create a new table once the company register? but I need to store the table name as well and make the situation more complex.

Comment: SQL databases are designed to scale up gracefully in this kind of application. A table containing 100K rows is medium sized. A table containing 10 million rows (for example, your `Card` table) is large, but still well within the capacity of MySQL to access in a few milliseconds.

Comment: I agree with Ollie Jones. The column company_id is Card's foreign key to Company. Hence there is an index on it and access to a company's Cards will be fast. Nothing to worry about :-)